# How to upload image on Backendless in java?

Tags: java, android, backendless

I want to upload an image on Backendless in Java, Android. What is the best way?
I need that because I want other users to see the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is described in the API documentation:
https://backendless.com/docs/android/files_file_upload.html